# C calculates Euler number with less precision than expected

Tags: c, floating-point

I wrote this piece of code.  I think that is all right but when I run it, I obtain a bad result. This code is for calculate the Euler number. I will appreciate your answer.

The result that I expect is approximately 2.718281828459045 and I obtain the result 2.718281745910644:

- 2.718281828459045 (expected)
- 2.718281745910644 (actual)

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {

    int factor, counter, n = 1;
    float total = 0, division;

    while ( n <= 20 ) {
        counter = 1;
        factor = n;

    while ( counter < n ) {
        factor *= ( n - counter );
        counter++;
    } 

    division = 1.0 / factor;
    total = total + division;
    n++;
    }

    total = total + 1;

    printf( "La constante matematica e vale aproximadamente: %.20f\n", total);

    return 0;  

} /* Finaliza funcion main */
```

Comment: What result did you expect, and what result did you get?

Comment: Also, try to always use english variable names.

Comment: Ah yes, the "bad result" error message. Have you carefully dusted the warp containment field?

Comment: Whats wrong with it? La constante matematica e vale aproximadamente: 2.71828174591064453125 and the real e is 2.7182818...

Comment: Hmm. I am using a 64-bit system. Maybe you use something from last century with 32 bits?

Comment: Why do you recompute `factor` every single time from 1?

Comment: No, I am using too a 64-bit system :D

Comment: In which part of the program Kerrek??

Comment: @pbhd: The 1990s called. They want their crappy gas-guzzling SUV CPUs back. (Hint: basically all of the actually-modern CPUs, i.e. energy-efficient ones like ARM and most Atoms, are 32-bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while ( n <= 20 ) {
    contador = 1;
    factorial = n;

    while ( contador < n ) {
        factorial *= ( n - contador );
        contador++;
    } 
    // snip
    n++;
```

`int`, if it is a 32-bit integer type, can only hold the factorials up to `12!`. `13! = 6227020800` is too large for a 32-bit integer. Thus you have overflow, and the results are completely wrong.

You could get somewhat good results if `factorial` were a `double` or a 64-bit integer instead of an `int`.

The (relatively small) error your computation gives you is due to using `float` instead of `double` for `total` and `division`:

We compute a good approximation to `e` as a `double`

```
Prelude Text.FShow.RealFloat> FD $ exp 1
2.718281828459045090795598298427648842334747314453125
```

and convert that to a `float`:

```
Prelude Text.FShow.RealFloat> FF $ realToFrac it
2.71828174591064453125
```

Which is the value you got: `2.718281745910644` modulo the different precision in printing. And it's the same we get when computing `exp 1` as a float:

```
Prelude Text.FShow.RealFloat> FF $ exp 1
2.71828174591064453125
```

the closest `float` value to the desired result:

```
Prelude Text.FShow.RealFloat> FF 2.718281828459045
2.71828174591064453125
```

Comment: Hello! I changed the variable type to double, but it not make any effect on the program, it gives me the same result, whats wrong? D:

Comment: That's because you use `float` instead of `double` for the result, you can't get a better approximation than that with `float`s.

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much Daniel Fischer!! :DD

Comment: Yeah! The program works! :DD